# How to monitor memory usage for managed/unmanaged code

Tags: memory-leaks

I have an application that is built in C# .NET. It uses excel as a presentation layer and unmanged C++ as a processing engine. Is there a tool I can use to check for memory leaks for each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com) will instrument both managed and unmanaged code.  I have used it successfully to find memory leaks in managed/unmanaged project.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. The C++ code is a dll that is called from the .NET application, so I can not check independently.

Comment: I should probably add, I do not have access to the source code.

Comment: Right, but you can see unmanaged memory allocations and view the call stack to find out where they're coming from (ie, what chain in your code is inducing the allocation)